# In iphone ,lazy loading in tabviewcontroller application

Tags: iphone

give some idea about lazy loading,so that i can load more than 20 images in tableview in a scrollview and also use of pullto refresh concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through below link..

[http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial][1]

You need to implement Grand Central Dispatch/Multithreading... for showing the image and loading...

Answer (score 0):

There is apple reference code for lazy loading. It is essential for the images to be downloaded when they come into view. Lazy loading involves sending a request in the background without having to block the user.

There are few pull to refresh implementations of pull to refresh on github and you can pick the one you will find good. They use the scroll view delegates to determine how much the scroll view has moved.